# how to tilt a canvas in the ondraw method inside a view

Tags: android

In my OnDraw method, I draw path into my canvas (circle with segements). All work well, now what I am not sure how to do is how can I tilt it (sort of rotation around one axis).

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is something like the tilt functionality of google map.

Here is the pseduo code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

      // I do all the drawing here

   canvas.tilt(45degrees)    <-----??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to create the tilt effect within the `onDraw` method modifying your canvas manually. Instead use [`setRotationX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationX%28float%29) method on the whole `View`. You can also define it in xml as `android:rotationX="45"`.

Comment: Perfect .. that does it. I didn't know that this exist.

Comment: SO does not let me award the bounty today and asks me to wait for couple of hours. So I will award it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Use `Canvas.concat(Matrix)` with a rotation matrix, i.e.:

```
class MyView {

    private final Matrix rotate = new Matrix();

    public MyView()
    {
        rotate.setRotate(45.0f);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.concat(rotate);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Note also that you should not do any memory allocations inside `onDraw()` as per the android linter.

Comment: Hmm That's interesting. I will try it.  Can I do this code at the end of the ondraw (after my drawing) or at the beginning? Also , wil lthis keep adding to the previous rotation (append kind of rotation) or will it do it to the same level

Comment: actually now I am thinking about it, this will rotate the image around. I am looking for tilting backward

Comment: Edited my answer with save/restore of canvas state. *Tilting backwards* will probably require you to pre-transform the image pixels.

Comment: Stll my 2 questions hold: 1- Where do I put the above code with relation to my drawing code? How can I tilt backward as this is really what the question is about

Comment: You need to `concat()` the transformation matrix before drawing. It basically moves the coordinates of every drawing operation by the specification inside the matrix. I'm not quite sure if you can emulate a tilt (especially of 45 degrees) this way, however.